# Can't find wrapper/dists in gradle folder in react native project

Tags: react-native, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying  to find my gradle/wrapper/dists in my react  native project but i cant find it. I only find `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` and
`gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Answer (score 0):

The wrapper itself should be in `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`, where `~` is your home directory. `/User/login` on Mac, `/home/login` on Linux and somewhere in `C:\Users` for that third OS.

Comment: Yh..I got that. But I can't find ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists in the project at all ..I am using linux ubuntu

Comment: It is not in a project direcotry, it is in you home directory.